# What is self-interference channel matrix in full-duplex system?

Tags: digital-communications, channel

I am learning about full-duplexing systems, and I saw that we have self-interference (SI) in the systems.
I read some papers that model the SI channel of the base station ${H_{SI}} \in \mathbb{C}^{L \times L}$, where $L$ is the number of antennas. Like in this paper ([Full-duplex paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7510760)), they said "The EH channel and the SI channel are modeled as Rician fading channels with Rician factor 6 dB".

What I am still wondering here are:

- Do they just generate a random matrix ${H_{SI}}$ based on the Rician distribution and with just the Rician factor? As in my code, I generate the channel between the users and the base station as $22.7 +26\log_{10}2.4 + 36.7\log_{10}d$, where $d$ is the distance from the users to the base station.
- What is the Rician factor they are mentioning here, and how to generate a random number according to this Rician factor? as I read the Rician distribution has 2 factors, which are $K$ and $\Omega$

Thank you in advance ^^